# Data import error: importing csv into R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to import sanfrancisco salaries csv file into R:

```
sfs<-read.csv("Salaries.csv",header=TRUE, colClasses = c("numeric","factor","factor","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","character","factor","factor"))
```

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines,
>   na.strings,  :  scan() expected 'a real', got 'NotProvided'